# MYSQL SELECT with INNER JOIN with multiple WHERE/CONDITIONS from the same column

Tags: mysql

I need to perform a SELECT on the PRODUCTS table
that only returns result if the conditions of the PRODUCTS_DETAILS table are true

follow the sql:

```
select p.* from products p
join products_details pd
on p.id = pd.id_product
WHERE pd.details = 'quadra mar'
AND pd.details = 'prédio novo'
```

however when I put two or more "**AND**" it does not return results

**objective**: search for all products that have the "**where**" details

Comment: try OR instead of AND

Comment: "OR" is not my goal, I only need it to meet the conditions 'QUADRA MAR' and 'PRÉDIO NOVO', if I use "OR", it will search even if ID 2 does not have 'PRÉDIO NOVO'

Comment: I guess it's not possible for pd.details to be 'quadra mar' and 'prédio novo' at the same time.

Comment: @stersym,is there any other alternative?
I'm a beginner in MYSQL

Comment: Alternative to what. You are asking for something impossible. (Unless i'm misundestanding something). Is there any way that your Column Details would have the values 'quadra mar' AND 'prédio novo' at the same time in the same row? Show us an example of your table.

Comment: @stersym Exactly, there is no possibility because in the PRODUCTS_DETAILS table, there are several records that are identified by ID_PRODUCT
so, somehow, I need to SELECT if there are two records in the PRODUCT_DETAILS table with conditions 'quadra mar' and 'prédio novo'

Comment: Are you looking for rows where product I’d is the same but details is different?

Comment: @P. Salmão, maybe I couldn't explain it so well, but I believe my request was very simplified, check the answer below, question finished, thank you very much for your attention and dedication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM products p
INNER JOIN product_details pd ON p.id = pd.id_product 
                              AND pd.details IN ('quadra mar', 'prédio novo');
```

Take a look in your `WHERE` clause, I think an `OR` condition will fix your issue too.

```
... WHERE pd.details = 'quadra mar' OR pd.details = 'predio novo'
```

And if you want only products that contains all the conditions in where clause, you can try:

```
SELECT pd.id_product, pd.details 
FROM products p
INNER JOIN product_details pd ON p.id = pd.id_product 
                              AND pd.details IN ('quadra mar', 'prédio novo') 
GROUP BY pd.id_product, pd.details 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comment: @rodrigão, me salvou, seu último código me serviu perfeitamente, segue:

select p.* from products p
join products_details pd
on p.id = pd.id_product
AND pd.details IN ('quadra mar','prédio novo','frente mar')
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING count(*) > 2;